# EF Core missing field from query

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I added some columns to the SQL Server database and use EF Core cml to update my models.

But somehow the command that EF core create always missing the new added fields.

I'm not sure what wrong with my models since I update from database.

Does anyone knew what happen it might be?

Comment: revise the migration, and delete the fields that been added to the schema, then ensure those fields are in the model, and then create a new migration with these changes.

Comment: Also, you could open the migration file, and fix it manually.

Comment: Thanks for response, @iSR5. I didn't use migration from ef core cmd or Add-Migrations. I generate the models from database as database first. In my model and context class I saw the updated fields but when I query from db. The fields are getting null.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a revision of the database snapshot and migrations that were created. There you can find if the field is present in your migration.

if no - you need to re-create migration.
if it is development version - than you can even remove all migrations and create from scratch.

if it is production version than you can query from [dbo].[__EFMigrationsHistory] and see if all migrations were applied and you have the field in it.

also it is possible to update [dbo].[__EFMigrationsHistory] to re-run it again.

if it is not enough you can create migration script

```
    dotnet ef migrations script --output "../../scripts/yourscriptname.sql"
```

and validate plain sql if the field is present